How to "continue" baking physics after adding frames
I want to find a way to not recalculate physics in a long simulation when I decide to append frames in a scene.  It seems like there should be a way to continue a bake from the previous end-frame, rather than delete and redo a bake where all the previous frames will remain the same.   I thought perhaps the "Update All to Frame" button would do this.
According to documentation:
Update All to Frame

    Bake all physics systems in the scene to the current frame.

However it doesn't seem to do anything if there is already baked frames, and seems to work identical to "Calculate To Frame" (sub-question OMG: what's the difference?!).

I realize that in my example, the fact that I drive sim-end-frame by a scene-end-frame, does not trigger any additional baking.
Is there a feature that will save me time as I evolve/add-to my scenes animation?  In my specific case I want to continue to animate a character and have the lattice soft-body effect the character's hair.
Example included: 
Example w/out bake-end driver: 

The end of the simulation cache is on a driver. That just seems likely to update improperly or break. Try removing the driver and manually setting it to 70, then doing “Update all to frame.”

@TheLabCat --  Yes I edited my question to comment on the driver that doesn't help.   However Update still doesn't work because the sim-end is locked with the bake, and would be on 50, so Update isn't helpful.   I don't want to set bake-end to something high (highest expected future scene end-frame), because I would indeed be continuing to reposition objects that would effect the bake.  I will update my example file in a few secs.
